# Adding multiple points to Google Map with Javascript v3 API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been stuck on this for a few days now. I'm having issues adding multiple points to a map using v3 of the Javascript API.

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514152/adding-points-to-google-map-api) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218616/not-able-to-set-multiple-markers-on-the-goole-maps-using-google-map-javascript-ap) and also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572981/multiple-markers-not-showing-in-google-maps-with-javascript-api-v3) on SO and I've caught a few mistakes and made some changes, but I still can't quite get anything to display except for the HTML text in `map_canvas`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Current iteration of code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });

    function initialize() {
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.84659,-84.35686),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var google_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

        var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'loading'
        });

        var t = [];
        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var h = [];

        t.push('Location Name 1');
        x.push(33.84659);
        y.push(-84.35686);
        h.push('<p><strong>Location Name 1</strong><br/>Address 1</p>');

        t.push('Location Name 2');
        x.push(33.846253);
        y.push(-84.362125);
        h.push('<p><strong>Location Name 2</strong><br/>Address 2</p>');

        var i = 0;
        for ( item in t ) {
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:       google_map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title:     t[i],
                position:  new google.maps.LatLng(x[i],y[i]),
                html:      h[i]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(this.html);
                info_window.open(map, this);
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
</script> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;">Google Map</div>
```

Comment: You may also consider [gis.se]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
info_window.open(map, this);
```

It should be:

```
info_window.open(google_map, this);
```

because there's no variable here named `map`. Working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/2DBXY/

If you're not doing so yet, try using a tool like Firebug or the Chrome console - debugging Javascript is almost impossible without one.

Comment: WOW. It's always the little things isn't it?! Seriously, thanks.

Comment: Oddly enough. I posted the code above in a codepen and it worked as it is with map vs. google_map.  I took out the `info_window.open(map, this);` line completely and it still worked: 
http://codepen.io/chris0/pen/MbWYEg